# Ubuntu multipass - VMM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virt-manager, multipass

How to show Ubuntu miltipass machines in Virtual Machine Manager?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: how  show it  ?   where is some example

Comment: Please alter the question and don't use comments to alter the scope of the question.

Comment: I change question. any info how to do it ?

Comment: If the answer does not work pm me. We don't use virtmanager anymore so this is from old notes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-requisites (virt-manager uses libvirt so you need these two; if already installed skip this):

```
sudo apt-get install virt-manager libvirt-daemon-system
```

To allow multi-pass to use libvirt

```
snap connect multipass:libvirt
```

The stop multipass and change the driver

```
multipass stop --all
sudo multipass set local.driver=libvirt
```

and virt-manager will show the multipass machines listed.

To revert back to qemu:

```
multipass stop --all
sudo multipass set local.driver=qemu
```

And if no longer needed remove/purge virt-manager too:

```
sudo apt purge virt-manager
```